# Django-SES BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, django, amazon-ses, django-ses

I am trying to send email from `django` with `django-ses` library but getting error:

```
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>7e2103e0-729f-11a9-aq25-51a2dqa8ae97</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I verified the domain and verified admin address `admin@...com` address in AWS console and created API key and secret from the SES dashboard.

Django settings:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-1' # because I use ireland server, but same error without this

SERVER_EMAIL = 'admin@...com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '"Hello You" <no-reply@...com>'
```

and I try to send email with:

```py
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings

email = EmailMessage(
    'Hello', 
    'World', 
    settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, 
    to=['mail@example.com']
)
email.send()
```

What can be a problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making Call by API (sendemail or sendrawemail) not SMTP.

AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

The Access key and secret key here should be IAM user keys who has access to SES.
To make an sendemail or sendrawemail Call, you need to use/create an IAM user from the IAM console and use those credentials, make sure the user has a policy allows access to SES.

If you get the keys from SES console , these only work for SMTP.

SMTP and general IAM credentials are different but you can convert them , refer below link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html